# setting session details to cookie

Tags: php, session

I created a project in xampp it works good,i uploadded it on two cpanel hosts 
http://t-nateghi.ir/lp/
and `http://mylp.ir/`
but it does not work in `http://mylp.ir/`
problem is in login page I think problem is unable to set session name and session id to cookie

Comment: Care to share some code?

Comment: I uploaded all content to https://mylp.ir/mylpir.zip

Comment: People are more likely to help you if you add the code to the question, and less inclined to download unknown, potentially harmful, zip files from a random URL.

Comment: can i send you cpanel username and password in private and you solve my problem?I cant send all codes here

Answer (score 0):

I founded the problem

Since session.use_only_cookies
is on
I have to write this code after writing user info to session
setcookie(session_name(),session_id());